# Can't get Adobe Media Server 5 to work with XAMPP's apache 2.4

Tags: xampp, streaming, media, apache2.4

I'm installing Adobe Media Server 5 and trying to get it work with already installed apache 2.4 from XAMPP.
The problem is when i'm trying to load the following modules apache just doesn't start..

```
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule f4fhttp_module modules/mod_f4fhttp.so
LoadModule hlshttp_module modules/mod_hlshttp.so
LoadModule jithttp_module modules/mod_jithttp.so
LoadModule ctrlplane_module modules/mod_ctrlplane.so
```

These modules are included in modules folder of XAMPP's apache, but still in Windows Event Viewer i get this message:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 181 of D:/SERVER/XAMPP/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_default.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found
```

and so on... Any help will be appreciated.
I'm using Windows 8.1 x64